# Compiling Code in UA Modeler showing up SKD issue

Tags: .net, opc-ua, unified-automation-sdk

I´m trying to compile the code of an information model in the UAModeler to create a server with UAExpert in .NET.

By the time I click on the "compile"-Button, I´ll get the response:
"SDK not configured correctly. Configurate SDK in Edit Settings dialog and generate code again"

Can someone help me with that issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?  Do you have UaSdkNetBundleBinary installed?  Which version?  What template do you have selected in your project settings?

Comment: @eglease: Thanks for reaching out. 
Got installed: 
- MS .NET SDK 6.0.400
- The current UA SDK with Standard 2.1
- As well as the UaSdkNetBundleBinary v3.1.3
- I might chosen template 3.8, not sure though

Now a new problem is showing up. I was able to compile the model and create a .csproj and .xml file with the aim of starting the server. When running the .csproj file with VisualStudio22 an error is showing up, that the debug file: test.exe is not exisisting. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Is this your thread by any chance:  https://forum.unified-automation.com/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=7971.  Did you get it working?  If yes, how?

Comment: I was able to create a xml file by uninstalling and reinstalling all the recommended programms named in the link UA provided.
Yet, I am still stuck in creating a running server using the XML File.

Comment: Is this a new issue or the same described in this question?  If it is a new problem, please create a new question and mark this one as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps solved the problem:

1. Install .NET SDK
2. Configure installation location of the sdk

I've installed:

1. MS .NET SDK
2. UA SDK Bundle

As a reference see: https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uamodeler/1.6.7/html/net_preparation.html